# How to determine if a column is unsigned?

Tags: mysql, database-metadata

I'm currently trying to list all columns of a specific table and determine if each column is unsigned or not.

Here, an example of my test fixture:

```
CREATE TABLE ttypes
(
    cbiginteger BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    cinteger INT UNSIGNED,
    csmallinteger SMALLINT UNSIGNED
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

In order to list all columns of a specific table, I have found two possibilities:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS
FROM ttypes;
```

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html), this query returns these fields: Field, Type, Null, Default, Extra & Comment. None of them allows me to determine if a column is unsigned or not.

After that, I look at the [`information_schema.columns`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) which is the base table used by the `SHOW COLUMNS` query.

```
SELECT ...
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'ttypes';
```

Unfortunately, none of the result fields allows me to determine if a column is unsigned or not.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only place those attributes are stored is in `COLUMN_TYPE` in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

That should be included in the output from `SHOW COLUMNS` (within `Type`):

```
mysql> show columns from ttypes;
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cbiginteger   | bigint(20) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cinteger      | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| csmallinteger | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Unfortunately you'd have to parse out the contents of `Type` and find `unsigned`, or not `unsigned` in there - it doesn't put anything in for signed columns.

Answer (score 9):

Try this magic:

```
select COLUMN_NAME,
       COLUMN_TYPE, 
       IS_NULLABLE, 
       IF(COLUMN_TYPE LIKE '%unsigned', 'YES', 'NO') as IS_UNSIGNED 
       from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='record1'
```

Output

```
COLUMN_NAME  COLUMN_TYPE       IS_NULLABLE  IS_UNSIGNED
-----------  ----------------  -----------  -----------
id           int(10) unsigned  NO           YES
recordID     varchar(255)      YES          NO
```

Answer (score 4):

To determine type for all variables in a table you can run a query like this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_TYPE from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='ttypes' and COLUMN_TYPE LIKE '%unsigned%'
```

After that your can easily determine type for a specific variable (for example the cinterger) with a query like this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='ttypes' and COLUMN_TYPE LIKE '%unsigned%' and COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'cinteger'
```

The above code will return the name of the variable searched only if it is unsigned.

At last your can using a mysql loop, procedure or your favourite scripting language to use this result and/or continue searching other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody stumbles upon this for the MySQL driver in .net, using GetSchema() like me, here is how the unsigned info is available.

```
_connection.GetSchema("Columns")
```

[image]

And then:

[image]

Hope this is not completely out of place for the question, and helps someone looking for programmatically determining the sign.

Answer (score 0):

I was using SQLColumns to get the type name through ODBC.  This worked with versions of the Connector/ODBC before 8.0.29.  Starting with 8.0.29, it no longer includes "unsigned" and I can no longer get the type that way.